# I am actually having troble with writing the code for the first part of loop where a foreward counting is there but skipping all the number...Got me

Tags: java, for-loop

[image]
I was trying to figure out this but can't do this even after a lot of trouble

Comment: So what have you tried up to this point? Can you share it and point to exactly where you are having trouble?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: i plan of writing the code by first writing a forward counting skipping all but the last digits(which i am unable to figure out how),then printing a 0 on the same line followed by a reverse counting(which i know how to write)..All in a nested for loop....Am I wrong anywhere...Just correct me cuz I started java just 10 days ago maybe so my knowledge is little....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The pattern 6 of this article may help you: 
https://javaconceptoftheday.com/how-to-create-pyramid-of-numbers-in-java/

You have to change the interval numbers.
I hope if I could help you a bit.